# How do I establish a parameter in SSRS report

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I am new to SSRS.

I have a dataset that pulls in values from a table and displays them in a report.
One of these columns in the dataset is the "Date_Recieved" column.

I want to add a "start" and an "end" [calendar date selector] that will filter the rows displayed on the report if they fall between the "Start Date" or "End Date".

In other words I want to filter the rows displayed in the report based on whether the value they contain for the "Date_Recieved" column falls between the start/end date that the user has selected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How is the dataset being populated? Raw SQL or a View or a Stored Procedure? as this will change how the solution will be?

If you are using a Stored Procedure.
You will need to setup two parameters @startDate and @endDate.

The stored procedure will have two parameters and you pass these into the data set via the parameter tab on the dataset menu.

If you are using a View or RAW SQL you will need to add a where clause to the SQL like such:

```
Where cast(Date_Recieved as date) between @parameter1 and @parameter2
```

then in the parameters section of the dataset options you will see these two appear and populate them with the @start and @endDate.

Comment: This has worked for me in the past and is the right approach for the OP.

Comment: You guys are too cool. Let me check this out and get back to you.

Comment: @thisnote If this solves your particular problem, it's recommended to upvote the answer and mark it as accepted. This will help other people in the future who experience a similar problem know what the appropriate fix was.

Comment: @AnthonyForloney affirmatory. However, I am recieving an error now that states "Query execution failed for dataset "dataset1" must declare the scalar variable @startdate"

Comment: @thisnote Which approach were you taking, the adding parameters into your stored procedure approach? If so, then you must declare the parameters underneath the stored procedure declaration.

Comment: Are you trying to use the RAW SQL, View or Stored Procedure approach?  Either way on the left side of the Dataset window you will see Query, Fields, Options, Filters, and Parameters on the Parameters you need to make sure that the View, Raw SQL or Stored Procedure parameters are mapped to an SSRS parameter.